# Creating a custom palette in microsoft charting

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, microsoft-chart-controls

Is there a way to create my own charting palette in which I can specify my own colors?

The ones that are available from

```
  chart.Palette = System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting.ChartColorPalette. //palette
```

do not really fit in with our design, so creating my own would be nice if this is possible thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can define your own palette using chart's PaletteCustomColors collection.

```
chart.PaletteCustomColors.Add(Color.Red);
chart.PaletteCustomColors.Add(Color.Blue);
```

Also if you need to control a color of each datapoint use the datapoint's color:

```
chart.Series[0].Points[0].Color = Color.Red;
```

Note: Bind chart to data *before* setting the datapoint colors.