# set font size in the graph via code

Tags: c#, winforms, microsoft-chart-controls

I created a series of a graph in C# windows forms with the [`Chart` control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datavisualization.charting.chart%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), but I need to change the font and color of the data series via code.

I'm adding a data serie at runtime like this:

```
     this.Chart_PlanComp.Series.Add("Qtde_Componente");
```

Comment: Not to mention not telling us anything about what kind of graph it is.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3737652/creating-a-custom-palette-in-microsoft-charting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the color like this:

```
var serie = Chart_PlanComp.Series.Add("Qtde_Componente");
serie.Color = Color.Green;
```

---

Though, setting the font doesn't seem to work...

```
var serie = Chart_PlanComp.Series.Add("Qtde_Componente");
serie.Font = new Font("Courier New", 15.0f, FontStyle.Italic); //changes nothing
```

Not even if you set it before adding:

```
var series = new System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.Series();
series.Font = new Font("Courier New", 15.0f, FontStyle.Italic);
this.chart1.Series.Add(series);
//still nothing
```

Answer (score 3):

```
System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.Series series1 = new System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.Series();
series1.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Trebuchet MS", 9F);
series1.LabelForeColor = Color.AliceBlue;
this.Chart_PlanComp.Series.Add(series1);
```